# Laravel session/flash variables not persisting after redirect

Tags: php, laravel, session-variables

So I'm trying to redirect with a session/flash variable, but I can't seem to figure out why the session variable is never present after the redirect.

I have a controller action like this:

```
public function verifyAction(Request $request)
{
    return redirect()
        ->route('login')
        ->with('test', 'Test');
}
```

and on the login route I'm dumping the session (using Laravel's Session()->all() function), however it never seems to contain the 'test' key.

I'm using 'artisan route:list' to show the routes like this:

```
+--------+----------+--------+--------+---------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI    | Name   | Action        | Middleware |
+--------+----------+--------+--------+---------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | login  | login  | @loginAction  | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | verify | verify | @verifyAction | web        |
+--------+----------+--------+--------+---------------+------------+
```

and both routes are using the web middleware as specified in the docs ([laravel.com/docs][1]) but the session data is always empty after the redirect, like this:

```
["_flash"]=>
array(2) {
    ["old"] => array(0) {}
    ["new"] => array(0) {}
}
```

I'm expecting to see the 'test' key in the _flash array after the redirect but actually it's always empty.
Any ideas what's going on here and how I could get it working?

One thing that strikes me as strange is that I can add normal session variables in the controller like this and it works fine:

```
Session::put([
    'test-2' => 'Testing'
]);
```

So session variables work fine, it's just flash variables that aren't working.

Distro: Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo), Laravel 5.8, Laradock, Docker version 18.09.5, build e8ff056, Php 7.2.15.

**EDITS**

Browser activity:

Request URL: http://localhost/verify?code=ABC&uid=2
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Request URL: http://localhost/login
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: What session drivers are you using?

Comment: @markus 'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'), and in .env: SESSION_DRIVER=redis

Comment: Try to use `load` instead of `with` @Donal.Lynch.Msc

Comment: Maybe the directory where laravel stores the sessions is not writeable. Please make sure that you grant read/write access to `storage/framework/sessions` for your web user.

Comment: @mare96 Tried it: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse::load()

Comment: @Markus Directory has 777 permissions: drwxrwxrwx 2 laradock laradock 20480 May 20 23:49 sessions